# iphone app approval question

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

I'm about to submit an app for approval and have a quick question:

it's a simple app for drink recipes and i was wondering if it's ok to use brand names in the app, like 'Stoli Vodka' ?

I've put the reg. trademark symbol next to the brand.

thanks in advance.

Comment: That's tricky to answer... I'm not sure anyone is going to be able to answer this effectively without being subjective or resorting to conjecture.

Comment: This is a question of trademarks, and is not programming related, so it's not really appropriate for this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store" rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it's not a good. Apple will almost certainly approve it though. They are not the copyright police and will not dig into your affairs to see if you have permission. They will hound you though if you use their trademarks.

You will need to get permission from the brand owners.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not legal, however your app can pass successfully the Apple test , for instance it exists an App named iMario that use Nintendo brand name and this app was created by a man like you and me and his app has been approval ;-)